# Find the most used hashtag for each day?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

The following is a data snippet of my hive table,

```
2009-01-01 #aaa 2
2009-01-01 #bbb 3
2009-01-02 #ccc 1
2009-01-02 #ddd 1
```

The description of the table is

```
id         bigint
hashtag    string
dt         date
```

The table basically has information of the hashtag count on each day. I want to write a hive query which will return the most used hashtag on each day and also its count. For example,

```
2009-01-01 #bbb 3
2009-01-02 #ccc 1
2009-01-02 #ddd 1
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT a.dt,
       a.hashtag,
       b.id
FROM mytable a
JOIN
  (SELECT dt,
          MAX(id) as id
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY dt) b ON a.id = b.id
AND a.dt = b.dt
ORDER BY a.hashtag;
```